# New numpy array from attribute of objects in another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to do an element-wise attribute extraction from a numpy array? For example, say I have:

```
import numpy as np

class foo():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.bar = value

obj_array = np.empty((2, 2), dtype='object')
for i in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(obj_array.shape[1]):
        obj_array[i, j] = foo(i+j)

bar_array_hard_way = np.empty_like(obj_array)
for i in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(obj_array.shape[1]):
        bar_array_hard_way[i, j] = obj_array[i, j].bar
```

Here, I have an array of objects. Each object has some attribute. I'm hoping there is a slick built-in way of extracting those attributes as a new numpy array. Obviously this is a pretty trivial example, but larger arrays the element-wise copying is pretty annoying.

Comment: This is almost certainly not working code, since `obj_array.size[0]` is invalid ... you mean `obj_array.shape`

Comment: use a [`recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest way will be to combine Python's  `operator.attrgetter` with numpy's `np.frompyfunction` - the first gives a fast, native code inlined, way to retrieve an object's attribute. The second, transforms an ordinary Python function into a Numpy's broadcast function, which can process an entire array in a single call -

so, your call is:

```
from operator import attrgetter
import numpy as np
# code to build obj_array
...
bar_array_easy_way = np.frompyfunc(attrgetter("bar"), 1, 1)(obj_array)
```

Quickly comparing it against using  `fromtiterator` built a 1 million int array from my objects in half the time - besides, `fromiterator` can't build arrays with `dtype=object` - just fixed size elements.

Note that `attrgetter` itself is rather a "function factory" - it takes an attribute name, and returns a function that will take any object and return that attribute. That returned function we pass in turn, to `frompyfunc` - which takes other 2 arguments in order to allow numpy to make its broadcasting magic: the number of input arguments and the number of return results for our function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your new array as:

```
bar_array = np.reshape(
    np.fromiter((x.bar for x in obj_array.flat), dtype=float),
    obj_array.shape)
```

Alter the `dtype` to whatever you'd please.