# Convert numpy elements to numpy dtypes

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a convenient way to convert the elements of a numpy array from arbitrary and unknown native python types to their equivalent numpy types? I could check the type of each element and convert each type individually, but I was hoping there might be a more convenient method.

I got python types in the new array by extracting an attribute of each object in an old array, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import attrgetter

class myobj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.myattr = value

obj_array = np.empty((3,3), dtype='object')
for i in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
        obj_array[i,j] = myobj(i+j)

native_type_array = np.frompyfunc(attrgetter('myattr'), 1, 1)(obj_array)
```

per this [question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714320/new-numpy-array-from-attribute-of-objects-in-another-numpy-array)

Comment: Can you deliver some code? How do you construct your numpy array with native python types in it?

Comment: What is the array dtype `myarray.dtype`? Unless it is `object`, are you sure the individual elements are Python objects? Try to fetch an element and check the `type`: `type(myarray[0])`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What kind of data do you store in the python types?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good question. Its kind of trivial- I just want the printed lists to look nice using numpy's set_printoptions. It could very well be that if this isn't very easy that I could come up with a wholly different solution thats better.

Comment: Yes, just use numpy arrays.

Comment: You do realize that you can't have a numpy array with different dtypes throughout? At that point, you'd be better off defining your own `__str__` or `__repr__` method for your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add to your code a `__repr__` method and some prints:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import attrgetter

class myobj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.myattr = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.myattr.__repr__()

obj_array = np.empty((3,3), dtype='object')
for i in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(obj_array.shape[0]):
        obj_array[i,j] = myobj(i+j)

native_type_array = np.frompyfunc(attrgetter('myattr'), 1, 1)(obj_array)
print(native_type_array.shape)
print(native_type_array.dtype)
print(native_type_array)
print(obj_array)
```

I get

```
1011:~/mypy$ python3 stack38332556.py 
(3, 3)
object
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

`native_type_array` is also an object dtype array - that's what the doc for `frompyfunc` says it does.  But since the elements are numbers, the display looks nice.

And by giving `myobj` a similar `repr`, I get the same thing.  If I change the repr

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s>'%self.myattr
```

I get:

```
[[<0> <1> <2>]
 [<1> <2> <3>]
 [<2> <3> <4>]]
```

This applies to lists as well.  `print([myobj(10),myobj(11)])` produces `[<10>, <11>]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy routine `astype()`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1.2, 3.4, 5.6])
>>> arr = arr.astype(np.int)
>>> print(arr)
[1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are stored in the `myattr` attribute so I think you will need to specify this attribute explicitly. This should work

```
new_obj_array = np.frompyfunc(lambda x : np.int32(x.myattr), 1, 1)(obj_array)
```